# Using multivector residue theorem to evaluate multiple integrals

Tags: residue-calculus, multiple-integral, geometric-algebras

I recently started learning about Geometric Algebra and Geometric Calculus. Since the residue theorem can be generalized for multivector functions I wondered if one could use it to evaluate certain multiple integrals similar to evaluating real integrals by using the residue theorem of complex analysis.
Does anyone know if someone has already tried it?